# char buffer with zero length accomdates the integer

Tags: c++

I have a basic question, the `BUFSIZ` of value (8192) basically an Integer of size (4), accommodates the character array of size 0.

How is it really possible..

**The output**

```
 size of buf:0
 size of INT:4
 size of bufsize:4
num_process:24
 after num_process:24
max_process has reached for kblockd:0
```

**The code**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ServiceUtilCheck
{
    private:
    FILE *ptr;
    char buf[0];
    char cmd[1024];
    int m_max_num_process;

    public:
    ServiceUtilCheck()
    {
        m_max_num_process=15;
    }


    bool check_max_process(const char* processname)
    {
        int num_process = 0;
        int ret =0;

        sprintf(cmd, "/bin/ps -e | /bin/grep %s | /usr/bin/wc -l", processname);

        if ((ptr = popen(cmd,"r")) != NULL )
        {
            if (fgets(buf,BUFSIZ,ptr) != NULL )
            {

                //buf[0] = (char) 3424252;
                cout<<" size of buf:" << sizeof(buf) <<endl;
                cout<<" size of INT:" << sizeof(int) <<endl;
                cout<<" size of bufsize:" << sizeof(BUFSIZ) <<endl;
                num_process =atoi(buf);
                cout<<"num_process:" << num_process <<endl;
            }

            cout<<" after num_process:" << num_process <<endl;

            if (num_process <= m_max_num_process)
                ret = true;

            pclose(ptr);
        }
        return ret;
    }
};


int main ()
{
    ServiceUtilCheck *serv = new ServiceUtilCheck();
    bool max_process= serv->check_max_process("kblockd");
    cout<<"max_process has reached for kblockd:"<< max_process <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Line numbers...  ARGH!!!

Comment: Because you're `fgets()` call is immediately walking past your `buf` and into your `cmd` (or some other stack space). No matter, it is **undefined behavior**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no array bounds checking in c++. So if your allocated size is less than as many bytes as you read, there is no compilation error.

However, your program can crash any time or worst over write memory of some other meaningful information silently. Like mentioned in comments already, this is undefined behavior.

Lastly, 0 sized array's are a special feature of GNU c. They are used to accommodate dynamically sized data and would be allocated at run time withe the actual size with function such as malloc.

[Zero length arrays](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html)

Comment: The reason i was checking is that, i am using some static analyzer tool in which i found issues says that the BUFSIZ of value (8192) , but the declared buf is of 1024, eg: char bug[1024], so probably i was testing with zero length, still not crashing, very doubtfull so i asked my questions here.

Comment: static analysis is done on compile time, Not run time. So zero length array which if is allocated at run time would not be shown in it. However, we do not see any allocation call here. Not running into a crash is just a coincidence and you should never rely upon it. Any modern dynamically typed language (python, c# etc.) would give you a compilation error though when exceeding array bounds.

Comment: no static analysis tool like "fortify" (HP), does at the compile time. during full make you can give the option like fortify and analyze, finally generate the fpr report to view the analysis on the code.